# Bootstrap 4: Hiding a btn-group

Tags: bootstrap-4

Note: Bootstrap **4**

I have two button groups (reduced for simplicity).  I want to show one group on extra small displays and the other group on all other sizes.  I was doing this with hidden-xs etc on Bootstrap 3.  But on Bootstrap 4, I cannot get it to work at all.  My current code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group hidden-xs-down" roles="group">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button with an icon and text</a>
    ...
</div>
<div class="btn-group hidden-sm-up" roles="group">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Icon only button</a>
    ...
</div>
```

**Both** groups are **always** shown, regardless of screen size.  How can I show one group for **xs** and the other for all other sizes?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the hidden-*-up/down have been replaced.  Here is my code that works:

```
<div class="btn-group d-none d-sm-block" roles="group">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button with an icon and text</a>
    ...
</div>
<div class="btn-group d-sm-none" roles="group">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Icon only button</a>
    ...
</div>
```